# CarPlay communication app failed to handover Siri INStartCallIntent to main app

Tags: ios, voip, communication, carplay

After I added carplay-communication entitlement to our project, the CarPlay call using Siri query is not working anymore, steps as below:

1. Connect iPhone to CarPlay device.
2. Query “Hey Siri, Call Megan using {myApp}”
3. Siri said “Calling Megan Bowen”.
4. Nothing happened, my app on iPhone was not launched to make the call.
5. Disconnect CarPlay, the same Siri query can launch the my app and make the call successfully.

When debugging, I found if I use carplay-communication and CarPlay was connected, the “application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) in AppDelegate/SceneDelegate
” will NOT be invoked, so the userActivity that stands for start call intent in “INStartCallIntentResponse”(from Siri Extension) will not be handled.

So the question is does the carplay-communication entitlement support VoIP using Siri query? Any configuration I missed?

My Dev environment:

Xcode 13.4.1

iPhone 12 with iOS 15.5

Sony AX100/AX1000 infotainment system/CarPlay Simulator for Xcode 13.4.1

Project configuration:

Main app info.plist: NSUserActivityTypes: INStartCallIntent, INStartAudioCallIntent, INStartVideoCallIntent
Siri Extention info.plist: IntentsSupported: INStartAudioCallIntent, INStartCallIntent, INSearchCallHistoryIntent

CallKit/Siri Kit supported in my app

Answer (score 1):

CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate is a sub-protocol of UISceneDelegate, so the application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) in CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate(Not your main app) will be invoked if you are using the carplay-communication entitlement.

Comment: I spent hours today. Thanks ...